# python logging module record too many None

Tags: python, django, logging

it is my code,but in the logfile, there is too many None,why ? how can i remove it?

```
import logging, traceback, os
def loginit(trace):
    trace_len = len(trace)
    trace = trace[trace_len - 2][:2]
    callname = ((trace[0].split('/'))[-1])
    head = (callname.split('.')[0]).split('_')
    if len(head) == 1:
        logfilehead = head[0]
    else:
        logfilehead = head[1]

    lineid = trace[1]

    logger = None
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    handle = logging.FileHandler('file_name','a+')
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(process)d [%(asctime)s %(callname)s %(lineid)d] %(levelname)s: %(message)s')
    handle.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handle)
    logger.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)

    return logger,handle,{'lineid':lineid, 'callname':callname}

def DEBUG(msg, *args):
    if config.LOG_LEVEL < 5:return
    logger, handle, extra = loginit(traceback.extract_stack())
    kwargs = {'extra':extra, 'exc_info':1}
    logger.debug(msg, *args, **kwargs)
    handle.flush()
    logger.removeHandler(handle)
    logging.shutdown()
```

> 3650 [2013-09-11 02:06:12,357 dispatch.py 137] ERROR: start********** None
>
> 3650 [2013-09-11 02:06:12,359 dispatch.py 173] ERROR: action:login******* None
>
> 3650 [2013-09-11 02:07:09,273 dispatch.py 184] ERROR: ************ None

Comment: `start**** None`, `action:login*** None` and `**** None` are the messages that were logged (see http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes for what `%(message)s` means in your logging.Formatter line). That means that the code you have that's calling these logs is what is producing these, not the logging code you've got above. Could you add the code from dispatch.py to your post?

Comment: log.ERROR('start ***').there is no None in my code